# Android Facebook Share Not Working

Tags: android, facebook, feed

I have spent quite much time trying to implement Facebook share with no success. I have tried various implementations and read quite a few Q&As related to similar problems I had occurred.

I have as much as simple Facebook Example does. What I want is to set description or at least message of the feed dialog. This is what I have added to example's code:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("caption", "1000vaikai Caption...");
parameters.putString("description", "This is a description"); // the message to post to the wall
parameters.putString("user_message_prompt", "This is message prompt");
parameters.putString("user_message", "MEEEESAGE");

mFacebook.dialog(Example.this, "feed", parameters,
                 new SampleDialogListener());
```

But it has no effect. There is nothing preset, just a plain feed dialog. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/) it says dialog methods has key-value parameters but I can't find a list of them. As you can see, I tried using parameters from the feed URL but it doesn't work.

Anyone got it working properly?

**EDIT**
I hacked Facebook SDK and it seems to generate proper URL (https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed + my parameters + ones taken from Facebook SDK itself). That means it DOES use same parameters as the ones listed in documentation about feed dialog page. But it still doesn't work. These parameters are being set:

- user_message
- redirect_uri
- description
- app_id
- display
- caption
- access_token
- user_message_prompt

Only app_id (I can see my app name), access_token (share actually works) and redirect_uri (it redirects back to mobile app) seem to have the effect

Comment: _“Here it says dialog methods has key-value parameters but I can't find a list of them”_ – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: My code shows these parameters in use but they have no effect. Seems like they are different in Facebook Android SDK.

Comment: Try giving the "name" param too

Comment: What do you want to post here, a picture with a message, a link with a message, or just a message?

Comment: A simple message. Preferably so that user would not be able to change it.

Comment: "name" parameter does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

So I have figured out that you must provide either a *link* or *picture*. If not - it simply ignores all the over parameters.